# AWK command to extract distinct values from a column

Tags: awk

From a tab delimited file. I'm trying to extract all rows based on a unique value from column 4 and then save it as a CSV. However, I would like to extract all the distinct values in column 4 and save them as CSV in one go.

I was able to extract one value using this command:

```
awk -F $'\t' '$4 == "\"C333\"" {print}' dataFile > C333.csv
```

Comment: Oh wow, this was the 16000th `awk`tagged question!

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider this test file:

```
$ cat in.csv
a       b       c       d
aa      bb      cc      d
1       2       3       4
12      23      34      4
A       B       C       d
```

Now, let's write each row to a tab-separated output file that is named after the fourth column:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{f=$4".csv"; print>>f; close(f)}' OFS='\t' in.csv
$ cat d.csv
a       b       c       d
aa      bb      cc      d
A       B       C       d
$ cat 4.csv
1       2       3       4
12      23      34      4
```

Comment: But this closes the file after each line is printed. Wouldn't it be more efficient to close the files in the `END` block?

Comment: One could sort the source data file on the fourth field first before applying that awk program to it.

Comment: @user000001 It would be efficient but not reliable.  With a large input file,  it is easy to reach the limit for the number of open files.  Because I've had OPs report this problem when they test code on their real data, I tend to opt for reliability over speed.

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes, sorting would be one way to avoid the issue of repeated opening and closing of files.